# How does spaCy tokenizer splits sentences?

Tags: tokenize, spacy

I am finding the tokenization code quite complicated and I still couldn't find where in the code the sentences are split.

For example, how does the tokenizer know that

`Mr. Smitt stayed at home. He was tired`

should not be split in "Mr." and should be split before "He".? And where in the code does the split before "He" happens?

(In fact, I am unsure actually unsure if I am looking at the right place: if I search for `sents` in `tokenizer.pyx` I don't find any occurrence)

Comment: Did you read this? https://spacy.io/docs/usage/customizing-tokenizer#how-tokenizer-works

Answer (score 1):

You access the splits via the doc object, with the generator:

```
doc.sents
```

The output of the generator is a series of spans.

As for how the splits are chosen, the document is parsed for dependency relationships. Understanding the parser is not trivial - you'll have to read into it if you want to understand it - it's using a neural network to inform the decision about how to construct the dependency trees; but the splits are those gaps between tokens which are not crossed by dependencies. This is not simply where you find a full-stop, and the method is more robust as a result.